# Load Prefab and AnimationClips from different AssetBundle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I'm trying to load Prefab from one AssetBundle and its corresponding AnimationClips from another.
So far loading the Prefab from AssetBundle and Instantiate are successful.

```
AssetBundle assetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(path);
if (assetBundle == null) {
     return;
}

GameObject prefab = assetBundle.LoadAsset<GameObject>(name);
Instantiate(prefab, targetTransform.position, targetTransform.rotation);
assetBundle.Unload(false);
```

Loading AnimationClips (Legacy animations) and adding it to the above instantiated Gameobject are also successful.

```
AssetBundle assetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(path);
if (assetBundle == null) {
     return;
}

List<AnimationClip> animationClips = new List<AnimationClip>();
foreach (string name in names) {
     AnimationClip animationClip = assetBundle.LoadAsset<AnimationClip>(name);
     if (animationClip != null) {
        animationClips.Add(animationClip);
     }
}
assetBundle.Unload(false);
```

When I try to play the animation, it is not working and I'm not getting any error though.

```
Animation animation = prefab.GetComponent<Animation>();

foreach (AnimationClip animationClip in animationClips) {
      string clipName = animationClip.name;
      animation.AddClip(animationClip, clipName);
}
foreach (AnimationClip animationClip in animationClips) {
      string clipName = animationClip.name;
      animation.PlayQueued(clipName, QueueMode.CompleteOthers);
}
```

Am I missing anything or how it should be done?

Comment: Prefab of what? A mesh with the Animation component attached to it?

Comment: @Programmer Yes Gameobject mesh and Animation component attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to play animation on the prefab instead of the instantiated object:

```
GameObject prefab = assetBundle.LoadAsset<GameObject>(name);
//You instantiated object but did nothing with it. What's the point of the instantiation?
Instantiate(prefab, targetTransform.position, targetTransform.rotation);
//Don't do this. The Animation is attached to the prefab
Animation animation = prefab.GetComponent<Animation>();
```

When you call the `Instantiate` function, it will return the instantiated Object. That returned object is what you should use to get the `Animation` component and then play your animation. Note that your code is not complete so there could be other issues but this one can also cause the issue you have.

```
GameObject prefab = assetBundle.LoadAsset<GameObject>(name);
//Instantiate the prefab the return the instantiated object
GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab, targetTransform.position, targetTransform.rotation);
//Get the Animation component from the instantiated prefab
Animation animation = obj.GetComponent<Animation>();
```

Now, you can play it.